# OpenERP specify multiple view references on "view_id"

Tags: odoo

I extended "hr.employee" class. (Inherited and gave the same name to the new one).
I defined two views (tree and form) and a menu:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="my_employee_tree">
   <field name="name">hr.employee.tree</field>
   <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
            ...
   </field>
</record>

 <record id="view_my_hr_employee_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.employee.form</field>
        <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            ...
   </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_my_hr_employee_seq">
        <field name="name">Angajati</field>
        <field name="res_model">hr.employee</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_my_hr_employee_form"/>
    </record>


    <menuitem id="menu_project_hr_base" parent="menu_project_utcn_project_base_main" name="HR"/>
<menuitem action="action_my_hr_employee_seq" id="menu_action_employee_form" name ="Angajati" parent="menu_project_hr_base"/>
```

What I want to do is to get the original views from hr.employee view when i use the original module, and to get my defined views when i use my module.

As you can see, I have specified "view_id" reference to my form view, but how can i define a reference also to my tree view? And I want the tree view to be shown first, and form view as alternative. How can i specify this?

```
<field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
```

seems not to work if i add reference to form view

Comment: but where exactly you wish to switch between your views ? on specific menu or at M2O, O2M or M2M view ?

Comment: I want to switch between the views as usual, from the up right corner of the screen

Comment: what do you mean by many2one,one2many,many2many view?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to map your action with particular `tree,form` view.

Try this:

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_my_hr_employee_seq">
    <field name="name">Angajati</field>
    <field name="res_model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window.view" id="act_hr_employee_tree_view">
    <field eval="1" name="sequence"/>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="your_tree_view_id"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_my_hr_employee_seq"/>
</record>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window.view" id="act_hr_employee_form_view">
    <field eval="2" name="sequence"/>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="your_form_view_id"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_my_hr_employee_seq"/>
</record>
```

Comment: Do you know why this method somehow doesn't work with kanban view?