# What is the right odoo 8 XML syntax for view_ids field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to customize the crm lead object. Class is defined this way

```
class yvleads(models.Model):
 _inherit = 'crm.lead'
 _name = 'crm.lead'
```

Now I added a menu item to display the added elements for which I have both a tree view and a form view. I have added a lett menu item referening a ir.actions.act_window. When this action is defined as

```
 <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="yvleads_mgt">
     <field name="name">Leads Yves</field>
     <field name="res_model">crm.lead</field>
     <field name="view_type">form</field>
     <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
     <field name="view_id" ref="tree_view_yves_leads"/>
 </record>
```

this works fine for the list-tree view but when I click on any item or the create button, I get the default form view for crm.

To add my customized view for form also, my understanding of [odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/actions.html#notquitem2m) is that I should use view_ids element but I was not able to get it right

I have tried several syntaxes with/without brackets, using eval="" or inside the xml definition but with no success. Searching this forum for string name="view_ids" was not very helfull, may be it is not the best practice to do that? any help appreciated

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="yvleads_mgt">
     <field name="name">Leads Yves</field>
     <field name="res_model">crm.lead</field>
     <field name="view_type">form</field>
     <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
     <field name="view_ids">(tree,tree_view_yves_leads),(form,form_view_yves_leads)</field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the right syntax :

```
<field name="view_ids"
                   eval="
                            [
                            (5, 0, 0),
                            (0, 0, {'view_mode': 'tree', 'view_id': ref('tree_external_id')}),
                            (0, 0, {'view_mode': 'form', 'view_id': ref('form_external_id')}),
                          ]"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

The *view_id* you used in your action is valid **only** when you click on the menu connected to that action.

What you need to *use* is [view inheritance](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html), i.e. you need to redefine the existing views:

```
    <record id="new_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">new view</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm_lead.existing_view_id"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
            ...
            </data>
        </field>
    </record>
```

inside the *data* tag you can accomplish the modifications you need following the instructions in the provided link.

In theory you could also change the whole view, but this could ba problematic if other modules inherits that same view.

This way every time you open *crm.lead* model in any way, your view is used.

Btw the correct syntax for view_ids would be:

```
<field name="view_ids" eval="[(6, False, [ref('view_id_1'), ref('view_id_2')])]">
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will look at inheritance her. Is it a problem if these views are shown only when we click on this particular menu items which would correspond to specific actions on the leads?

Comment: Also, looking at [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245354/openerp-specify-multiple-view-references-on-view-id) I have achieved what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think very useful for this link so please check it.

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/for-which-reason-can-i-add-a-value-to-view-ids-of-a-window-action-97682